# Proving that any continuous homomorphism of $\mathbb{R}/(2\pi\mathbb{Z})$ int0 $T$* is neccesarily an exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, exponential-function, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

This is an exercise form Katznelson's book on Harmonic Analysis, so I want to solve it using his hint.

T* here denotes the multiplicative group of units of complex numbers of unit norm.
That is to say T* = {$z \in \mathbb{C}$ | $|z|=1$ }

In a previous exercise, I was successful in showing that any infinite subgroup G of $A = \mathbb{R}/(2\pi\mathbb{Z})$ must be dense in $A$.

The hint given is to "determine the mapping on 'small' rational multiples of $2\pi$ and use [the exercise stated above]."

First, I observed that the homomorphism must send the identity to the identity hence 0 must get sent to 1.

So I have attempted this problem in various ways.  I'm just not sure how to define G.  I considered defining it as the group of all rational multiples of $2\pi$ (mod $2\pi$).  But this is not getting me anywhere: small rational multiples will converge to 0 hence their images must converge to 1 by continuity.  So what...?

I can also guess (intuitively, without proof) that the family of homomorphisms which would work must be of the form $x \mapsto e^{irx}$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R} $.

So in some sense, we need to show that an arbitrary continuous homomorphism should be of that form.

I have also observed that if we write down some $G$, and $G$ is dense in $A$ then by continuity the homomorphism is determined by its behavior on G.

But really, how do you solve this problem?
Thank you all for your suggestions!

Comment: Call the homomorphism $h$. Then $$h\left(\tfrac{m}{n}\cdot 2\pi\right) = \left(h\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\cdot 2\pi\right)\right)^m.$$ Choosing $m = n$ yields $h(n^{-1}\cdot 2\pi) = \exp(2\pi i k/n)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Use the continuity to show that if you choose $n$ large enough, you can conclude that $h(t) = e^{ikt}$, first for $t$ multiples of $2\pi/n$, then by the hint for all $t$.